# WinError 10060 and elipses(three dots)

Tags: python, imap, imaplib

```
import imaplib, email, os

user = 'mail'
password = 'pass'
imap_url = 'imap.gmail.com'
con = imaplib. IMAP4_SSL(imap_url)
con.login(user,password)
print(con.list())
```

> 

I am trying this on my IDLE and gmail account I made just for this; the internet is good and there are ellipses (three dots) seconds before error comes.

error msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/vinee/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/Email downloader.py", line 1, in <module>
    import imaplib, email, os
  File "C:\Users/vinee/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311\email.py", line 7, in <module>
    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com','992')
  File "C:\Users\vinee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\imaplib.py", line 1323, in __init__
    IMAP4.__init__(self, host, port, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\vinee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\imaplib.py", line 202, in __init__
    self.open(host, port, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\vinee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\imaplib.py", line 1336, in open
    IMAP4.open(self, host, port, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\vinee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\imaplib.py", line 312, in open
    self.sock = self._create_socket(timeout)
  File "C:\Users\vinee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\imaplib.py", line 1326, in _create_socket
    sock = IMAP4._create_socket(self, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\vinee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\imaplib.py", line 302, in _create_socket
    return socket.create_connection(address)
  File "C:\Users\vinee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socket.py", line 850, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "C:\Users\vinee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socket.py", line 835, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Comment: The syntax is correct.  Are you sure you had an Internet connection at the time?

Comment: The error traceback suggests that you have a local file named `email.py`, which is being imported instead of the system standard module of the same name.  Perhaps that is the issue.  Can you show us the contents of `C:\Users/vinee/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311\email.py` on your system.

Comment: Your traceback doesnt match.  For some reason you are connecting port 992 rather than 993.  993 is the correct port. [edit: as John says the traceback indicates you have a file named email.py, overriding the system email library, which is connecting incorrectly)